# How to sort in bash?

Tags: bash

I have several lines in file, just like below:

```
/adbc/eee/ddd/baa/
/adbc/fff/ddd/ccc/avfff/
/adbc/ccc/ddd/b/
/adbc/fff/ddd/c/
/adbc/ccc/ddd/bf/
/adbc/ccc/ddd/bc/
```

The sort algorithm must first get the string before last `/`, that is:

```
baa
avfff
b
c
bf
bc
```

and then sort it by the first character, and then the length of the string, and then alphabetically.

The expected result is

```
/adbc/fff/ddd/ccc/avfff/
/adbc/ccc/ddd/b/
/adbc/ccc/ddd/bc/
/adbc/ccc/ddd/bf/
/adbc/eee/ddd/baa/
/adbc/fff/ddd/c/
```

Comment: You don't sort with `bash`. Surprisingly enough, you sort with `sort` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) in a pre-processing step to add 3 columns all based on the field of the interest, feed to `sort`, then use `cut` to discard the extra fields

```
awk -F'/' -v OFS="/" '{x=substr($(NF-1), 1, 1);
  print(x, length($(NF-1)), $(NF-1), $0)}' file.txt |
  sort -k1,1 -k2,2n -k3,3 -t'/' |
  cut -f4- -d'/'
/adbc/fff/ddd/ccc/avfff/
/adbc/ccc/ddd/b/
/adbc/ccc/ddd/bc/
/adbc/ccc/ddd/bf/
/adbc/eee/ddd/baa/
/adbc/fff/ddd/c/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat sortthisfile | while read line
do
    field=$( echo $line | sed -e 's:/$::' -e 's:.*/::' )
    firstchar=${field:0:1}
    fieldlen=${#field}
    echo "${firstchar},${fieldlen},${field},${line}"
done | sort-k1,1 -k2,2n -k3,3 -t, | sed 's:.*,/::'
```

Obviously, `sortthisfile` is the name of your file.